# pyplot hist() frequency histogram does not normalize to 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a problem when using `hist()`. I created an array with 396 entries which contains every possible outcome of

```
X + 0.5 Y + Z,
```

where `0 <= X,Z <=5` and `0 <= Y <= 10`. All I want to create is a frequency histogram whose bar heights coincide with the probability that a certain value is taken under the assumption of `x,y,z` being independently, uniformly distributed. I thought I'd give `hist()` a try:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def activity(x,y,z):
    return 1 * x + 0.5 * y + 1 * z

rangex = np.arange(6)
rangey = np.arange(11)
rangez = np.arange(6)
rhs = 10
activities = [activity(x,y,z) for x in rangex for y in rangey for z in rangez]
activities = pd.Series(activities)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
n, bins, patches = axes.hist(activities, bins=np.linspace(-0.25, 15.25, num=32), \
                             normed=True)
```

Here is the weird thing: n sums up to **2**!!!
With the choice of `bins`, I made sure that each item falls into exactly 1 bin, and I know that there are exactly 31 bins necessary, because my value range is from 0 through 15 in steps of 0.5.

I am sorry I couldn't simplify this example. A random trial with 100 values yielded a correct frequency. Instead, this is what the histogram looks like: [image: bad normalization using pyplot.hist]

From the picture, it is obvious that the frequencies do not sum up to 1. There are, e.g., in the center 11 bars of height 0.1 or above.  The frequencies of the red plot, however, do sum up to 1.

*My question:* Why do I get a false normalization?

See below the code to manually calculate a correct histogram:

```
barposs, barheight = zip(*activities.value_counts(normalize=True).iteritems())
plt.bar(np.array(barposs) - 0.25, np.array(barheight), width=0.5, color='red')
```

I appreciate any useful comment on that.

Comment: This is a common source of confusion (and also a change in the underlying `numpy.histogram` function a few years ago). If you'll look closely, it still _integrates_ to 1, it just doesn't _sum_ to one.  (I'm guessing your bin width is 0.5 if things are summing to 2.) In other words, the widths of the bins are taken into account.  Have a look at the documentation for `numpy.histogram`, particularly the `normed` and `density` kwargs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. You are right about all bin widths to be 0.5. I would immediately mark this as answer, if it were one ;)

Comment: I found it is also weird and would ask the same question. There is a solution to normalize the historgram here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63831378/why-does-the-normalized-histogram-give-wrong-y-values-all-should-add-up-to-1.