# Why does the normalized histogram give wrong y values (all should add up to 1)? Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Trying to make a simple histogram (working) but when normalizing (density=1) - it gives incorrect y values since all should add up to 1

```
Dataset = [10,10.2,10.4,10.6,10.8,11.0,11.2]
Freqset = [1,3,7,9,6,5,2]
data =[]

for i in range(len(Dataset)):
    for j in range(Freqset[i]):
        data.append(Dataset[i])
print(data)

bins = len(Dataset)
plt.hist(data,bins,histtype='bar', density = 1,rwidth=0.8,alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title(f'Histogram')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `plt.hist` has a `weights=` parameter so you can create the histogram directly from the frequencies: `plt.hist(Dataset, bins, weights=Freqset, density=1)`. Also note that for discrete data, it is often more desirable to explicitly set the bin boundaries between the data points, e.g. `bins = np.arange(9.9, 11.4, 0.2)`, preventing the weird positioning of the bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `density` keyword argument is set to `True`, the output histogram is normalized by the sum of each bin count so it can be interpreted as a probability density.

Found in the `pyplot.hist()` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

> If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., the area (or integral) under the histogram will sum to 1.

So not the values should add up to 1, but the integral (taking into account the bin size). In you case, the bin size is `(max(Dataset) - min(Dataset)) / 7 = 0.1714`, so you need to multiply the histogram values by 0.1714, and it will sum to 1.

Comment: Note that in this case the width of the bins is `(max(Dataset) - min(Dataset)) / 7 = 0.1714`

Comment: Thank you very much for the information!!!!

Comment: True, I edit the answer. Thanks @JohanC.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Thank you for the information - having some difficulty implementing the advice but I will keep trying. I found the easiest (for now) is to simply create a list with the relative frequencies:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Dataset = [1350,1400,1450,1500,1550,1600,1650]
Freqset = [2,5,8,60,19,3,3]
Relativef = []

for i in range(len(Dataset)):
    Relativef.append(Freqset[i]/sum(Freqset))

print(f"Rel f: {Relativef}")
print(len(Relativef))

bins = len(Dataset)

plt.hist(Dataset,bins,weights=Relativef,rwidth=0.8, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Normalized Histogram')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think I figured it out and made an example in both Matlab and Python.  The idea was to automate physics experimental data processing and to draw the graphs....  See the link below for the code.    https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cd8dkv32qe9mjdv/AADiZHOTJ9TM5RCbzFRwHG5Xa?dl=0